# How to name resource file in android other than english

Tags: java, android, resources

I want to name my resource file something like レオウ.png (Japanese). However, there is error when loading that resource. I wonder if there is any way I can do that.

Comment: short answer: no you can't

Comment: +1 @PontusBacklund That's shortest correct answer :)

Comment: Only lowercase English characters and underscore are allowed (other than the dot)

Comment: You anyhow got the answer. But why on earth do you need to change resource name?

Comment: Because it's just a name. Just like any other variable name/method name in java. Right?

Comment: you need to develop your own java compiler and your own dvm to do this

Comment: thanks for comments! I have noticed that.

Answer (score 0):

All resources are ID'd into R.java. R.java must conform to programming nomenclature standards because, well, it's Java source code. Your resource name clearly violates this because identifiers can only be composed of _, a..z, A..Z and 0..9 characters (and can't start with a digit).
So just as you wouldn't create a variable with japanese kanji name, you likewise can't do that with a resource file, because you need to access it through R.java (R.drawable.xxx).